# Implementing __neg__ in a generic way for all subclasses in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I apologize in advance for the rather long question.

I'm implementing callable objects and would like them to behave somewhat like (mathematical) functions. I have a base class whose `__call__` method raises `NotImplementedError` so users must subclass to define `__call__`. My question is: how can I define the special method `__neg__` in the *base class* so subclasses immediately have the expected behavior without having the implement `__neg__` in each subclass? My sense of the expected behavior is that if `f` is an instance of (a subclass of) the base class with a properly defined `__call__`, then `-f` should be an instance of the same class as `f`, possessing all the same attributes as `f`, except for `__call__`, which should return the negative of `f`'s `__call__`.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class Base(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError, 'Please subclass'

    def __neg__(self):
        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            return -self(*args, **kwargs)
        mBase = type('mBase', (Base,), {'__call__': call})
        return mBase()                                                                                                                                                                                                  

class One(Base):
    def __init__(self data):
        self.data = data

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1
```

This has the expected behavior:

```
one = One()
print one()        # Prints  1
minus_one = -one
print minus_one()  # Prints -1
```

though it's not exactly what I'd like since `minus_one` is not an instance of the same class as `one` (but I could live with that).

Now I'd like the new instance `minus_one` to inherit all attributes and methods of `one`; only the `__call__` method should change. So I could change `__neg__` to

```
    def __neg__(self):
        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            return -self(*args, **kwargs)
        mBase = type('mBase', (Base,), {'__call__': call})
        new = mBase()

        for n, v in inspect.getmembers(self):
            if n != '__call__':
                setattr(new, n, v)

        return new
```

This seems to work. My question is: are there cons to this strategy? Implementing a generic `__neg__` must be a standard exercise but I couldn't find anything on it on the web. Are there recommended alternatives?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: This can be solved quite nicely with metaclasses.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem you're running into is that `__xxx__` methods are only looked up on the class, which means all instances of the same class will use the same `__xxx__` methods.  This suggests using a method similar to what Cat Plus Plus suggested; however, you also don't want your users to have to worry about even more special names (such as `_call_impl` and `_negate`).

If you don't mind the possibly mind-melting power of metaclasses, that is the route to take.  A metaclass can add in the `_negate` attribute automatically (and name mangle it to avoid clashes), as well as take the `__call__` that your user wrote and rename it to `_call`, then create a new `__call__` that calls the old `__call__` (now called `_call` ;) and then negates the result, if necessary, before returning it.

Here's the code:

```
import copy
import inspect

class MetaFunction(type):
    def __new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        result_class = type.__new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        if '__call__' in cls_dict:
            original_call = cls_dict['__call__']
            args, varargs, kwargs, defaults = inspect.getargspec(original_call)
            args = args[1:]
            if defaults is None:
                defaults = [''] * len(args)
            else:
                defaults = [''] * (len(args) - len(defaults)) + list(defaults)
            signature = []
            for arg, default in zip(args, defaults):
                if default:
                    signature.append('%s=%s' % (arg, default))
                else:
                    signature.append(arg)
            if varargs is not None:
                signature.append(varargs)
            if kwargs is not None:
                signature.append(kwargs)
            signature = ', '.join(signature)
            passed_args = ', '.join(args)
            new_call = (
                    """def __call__(self, %(signature)s):
                           result = self._call(%(passed_args)s)
                           if self._%(cls_name)s__negate:
                               result = -result
                           return result"""
                           % {
                               'cls_name':cls_name,
                               'signature':signature,
                               'passed_args':passed_args, 
                              })
            eval_dict = {}
            exec new_call in eval_dict
            new_call = eval_dict['__call__']
            new_call.__doc__ = original_call.__doc__
            new_call.__module__ = original_call.__module__
            new_call.__dict__ = original_call.__dict__
            setattr(result_class, '__call__', new_call)
            setattr(result_class, '_call', original_call)
            setattr(result_class, '_%s__negate' % cls_name, False)
            negate = """def __neg__(self):
                            "returns an instance of the same class that returns the negation of __call__"
                            negated = copy.copy(self)
                            negated._%(cls_name)s__negate = not self._%(cls_name)s__negate
                            return negated""" % {'cls_name':cls_name}
            eval_dict = {'copy':copy}
            exec negate in eval_dict
            negate = eval_dict['__neg__']
            negate.__module__ = new_call.__module__
            setattr(result_class, '__neg__', eval_dict['__neg__'])
        return result_class

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaFunction

class Power(Base):
    def __init__(self, power):
        "power = the power to raise to"
        self.power = power
    def __call__(self, number):
        "raises number to power"
        return number ** self.power
```

and an example:

```
--> square = Power(2)
--> neg_square = -square
--> square(9)
81
--> neg_square(9)
-81
```

While the metaclass code itself can be complex, the resulting objects can be very easy to use.  To be fair, most of the code, and the complexity, in `MetaFunction` is due to re-writing `__call__` in order to preserve the call signature and make introspection useful... so instead of seeing `__call__(*args, *kwargs)` in help, you see this:

```
Help on Power in module test object:

class Power(Base)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Power
 |      Base
 |      __builtin__.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __call__(self, number)
 |      raises number to power
 |
 |  __init__(self, power)
 |      power = the power to raise to
 |
 |  __neg__(self)
 |      returns an instance of the same class that returns the negation of __call__
```

Comment: While brain melting, this is the kind of abstraction I was ultimately looking for. Thanks for sharing this! I have to spend some time and study your code.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach has several downsides.  One example is that you copy all members of the original instance to the new instance -- this won't work if your class overrides any special methods other than `__call__`, since special methods are only looked up in the dictionary of the object's type when called implicitly.  Moreover, it copies a lot of stuff that is actually inherited from `object` and doesn't need to go in the instance's `__dict__`.

An easier approach that satisfies your exact requirements is to make the new type a subclass of the instance's original type.  This can be done by defining a local class inside the `__neg__()` method:

```
def __neg__(self):
    class Neg(self.__class__):
        def __call__(self_, *args, **kwargs):
            return -self(*args, **kwargs)
    neg = Base.__new__(Neg)
    neg.__dict__ = self.__dict__.copy()
    return neg
```

This defines a new class `Neg` derived from the original function's type and overwrites its `__call__()` method.  It creates an instance of this class using `Base`'s constructor -- this is to cover the case that `self`'s class would take constructor arguments.  finally we copy everything that is directly stored in the instance `self` to the new instance.

If I were to design the system, I'd take a completely different approach.  I'd fix the interface for a function and would only rely on this fixed interface for *every* function.  I wouldn't bother to copy all attributes of an instance to the negated function, but rather do this:

```
class Function(object):
    def __neg__(self):
        return NegatedFunction(self)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return SumFunction(self, other)

class NegatedFunction(Function):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return -self.f(*args, **kwargs)

class SumFunction(Function):
    def __init__(self, *funcs):
        self.funcs = funcs
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return sum(f(*args, **kwargs) for f in self.funcs)
```

This approach does not fulfil your requirement that the function returned by `__neg__()` has all the attributes and methods of the original function, but I think this requirement is rather questionable as far as design is concerned.  I think dropping this requirement will give you a much cleaner and more general approach (as demonstrated by including an `__add__()` operator in the example above).

Comment: Thanks! This is elegant. You're right about the more general design. I find it somewhat unsatisfying that `f` and `-f` are of different types. This makes it awkward to access `f`'s attributes via `-f` (e.g., its domain), but it's possible to work around that.

Comment: `NegatedFunction` serves as a proxy for the original function.  All interface methods need to be forwarded to the original function.  If the domain is part of your interface, you need to forward it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new type, you can keep a flag on the instance that says whether call result should be negated or not. And then you can offload the actual overrideable call behaviour to a separate (non-special) method, as part of your own protocol.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._negate_call = False

    def call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
        return -result if self._negate_call else result

    def __neg__(self):
        other = copy.copy(self)
        other._negate_call = not other._negate_call
        return other
```

Comment: Yes this is simpler. I was wondering if it could be done generically without introducing additional attributes. Also in your `__neg__`, I suppose `other._negate_call = True` should be `other._negate_call = not self._negate_call`. Otherwise `-(-one)` doesn't do the same as `one`.

Comment: @Dominique: Yeah, I had that there, but my brain is barely working at this hour.